# Simple Bash scripting

Tags: bash, cygwin

I'm trying to get to grips with Bash scripting via Cygwin. My script is about as simple as it gets.

I change the directory to the root of my C drive, and print the new location.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash 
cd /cygdrive/c
pwd
```

is saved in the file `chdir.sh` in my home directory.
I then call `./chdir.sh` from the bash prompt.  This results in the error

```
: No such file or directorygdrive/c
/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/rcotton
```

I definitely have a C drive, and the command `cd /cygdrive/c` works when I call it directly from the bash prompt.

I realise that this problem is likely stupidly simple; please can you tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just in case you have edited your script with an editor which is not part of 
the Cygwin environment (e.g., anything like 'Notepad*', 'WordPad', etc.): convert your script to Unix-lineendings via the 'dos2unix' tool.

The script itself is absolutely correct, no need for any / or \ changes. The error message

```
: No such file or directorygdrive/c
```

leads me to think of problems with the lineending since \r\n (Windows line ending). Just in case you do not have 'dos2unix' installed:

```
tr -d \\r < win.txt > unix.txt
```

or

```
sed -e 's/$/\r/' < unix.txt > win.txt
```

Comment: Very well called.  It was sneaky carriage returns causing the weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using forward slash, and not backslash, in your cd command? Your problem would be symptomatic of mistaking these two.

Try these variants if just a single forward slash produces is indeed there and produces this weird error:

```
cd //cygdrive//c
```

or

```
cd \\cygdrive\\c
```

Comment: `cd //cygdrive//c` gives the error `: No such host or network pathrive//c`.  `cd \\cygdrive\\c` gives the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

Try `#!/usr/bin/bash.exe` and see if that makes a difference.  Either works on my Cygwin install, but the file is actually named bash.exe.

Answer (score 0):

TO: ttarchala (and Mr Cotton)

In cygwin, `//start1/path_2/stuff/long` triggers UNC hack mode, which treats `start1` as a SMB server with share `path_2`.  This is not what was intended.

This will sometimes bite you in certain shell scripts that are shared with UNIX, where multiple forward slashes are always coalesced to a single slash.  In cygwin, multiple forward slashes are coalesced EXCEPT if it's the beginning one, which is UNC trigger mode.